# Finding latest version of anaconda automatically from bashrc

Tags: bash, shell, anaconda

I'm trying to create a code which will fetch the latest version of anaconda and install it.
Currently we can do this to install the latest version:

```
mkdir tmp
cd tmp
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2020.11-Linux-x86_64.sh
bash Anaconda3-2020.11-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

I want the script to be more generalized such that the code would automatically find the latest version of anaconda, download the shell script file and install it.

Comment: Is there a specific issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to get the latest version:

```sh
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/ -q -O- |\ 
   grep 'Anaconda3'| \ 
   sed -n 's|.*>Anaconda3-\([0-9]\{4\}\.[0-9]\{2\}\)-.*|\1|p'
   uniq |\ 
   sort -r |\ 
   head -1
```

This solution works *only* for those versions that use the year format (e.g. 2020-07), but since the latest version will presumably be of that format that should be fine.

Some explanation:

- `wget` to fetch the contents of the archive page, which gives us the HTML content containing all the download URLs. `-q` quiets the output, `-O-` prints to stdout. Alternatively, you can use `curl -s` to the same effect.
- `grep 'Anaconda3'` gives us the lines containing Anaconda, which contain the download links.
- Use `sed` to select the version strings from the download links, e.g. `2020-11`. That gives you a list of all versions (of the format YYYY-MM).
- Sort that lists and select the first entry, which is the latest version.

Use the version in the rest of your script and you are done. A complete solution would be:

```sh
version=$(wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/ -q -O- |\
   grep 'Anaconda3'|\
   sed -n 's|.*>Anaconda3-\([0-9]\{4\}\.[0-9]\{2\}\)-.*|\1|p' |\
   uniq |\
   sort -r |\
   head -1)
wget "https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-$version-Linux-x86_64.sh"
```

I'm sure fetching the latest version could be made more efficient, but this should be sufficient for your use case.